# C# how to recursively search object for objects of type x

Tags: c#, recursion

I need to retrieve all objects of type X from a complex object.

```
public class Dog
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
    public Owner Owner{get;set;}
    public Kennel Kennel {get;set;}
}

public class Kennel
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Address Address{get;set;}
    public List<Dog> Dogs {get;set;}
}

public class Owner
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string State {get;set;}
    public Address Address{get;set;}
}
```

If I have an object composed of Dog, I would need to retrieve all address objects in all child objects.

Comment: I cant see any recursion in your problem. You want 2 objects: owner address and kennel address

Comment: Sorry, the  Kennel should have a list of dogs

Comment: If dog is in the kennel, is his Kennel field set to kennel that contains it (that is to say, are tere any loops in this graph?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you might need to use [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) to retrieve the `Address` objects:

```cs
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static List<Address> GetAddresses(this Dog dog)
    {
        var addresses = new List<Address>();
        GetAddress(dog, ref addresses);
        return addresses;
    }

    private static void GetAddress(object property, ref List<Address> addresses)
    {
        if (property == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var props = property.GetType()
                            .GetProperties()
                            .Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsClass && 
                                       !p.PropertyType.IsPrimitive)
                            .ToList();

        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(Address))
            {
                var address = prop.GetValue(property) as Address;
                addresses?.Add(address);
            }

            var next = prop.GetValue(obj: property);

            // When property is a collection
            if (next is IEnumerable collection)
            {
                foreach (var item in collection)
                {
                    GetAddress(property: item,
                               addresses: ref addresses);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                GetAddress(property: next,
                           addresses: ref addresses);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

> And usage example:

```cs
var dogs = new List<Dog>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var dog = new Dog
    {
        Name = $"Dog - {i}",
        Age = 10,
        Kennel = new Kennel
        {
            Address = new Address()
        },
        Kennels = new List<Kennel>
        {
            new Kennel
            {
                Address = new Address()
            },
            new Kennel
            {
                Address = new Address()
            },
            new Kennel()
            {
                Address = new Address()
            }
        },
        Owner = new Owner
        {
            Address = new Address(),
            Kennel = new Kennel
            {
                Address = new Address()
            }
        }
    };

    dogs.Add(dog);
}

var address = dogs.Select(dog => dog.GetAddresses());
Console.WriteLine(address.Sum(a => a.Count)); // will print 30
```

> Please note that using Reflection could affect the performance of your application.

Comment: In your example, is it possible to account for a List of Kennel within dog?

Comment: Good question, I will check that and get back to you.

Comment: @AnxiousdeV I've updated the code to take into account collections, please check.

Comment: Thanks, I believe the PropertyType.IsClass will eliminate IEnumerable properties from being included

Comment: When an element's `IsClass` property returns `true` that doesn't mean it can't be `Enumerable`. 
The most simple reason is that `Enumerable` is also `class` (it's `IsClass` property returns `true` too).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need recursion here. Just SelectMany

```
Kennel home = getKennel();

List<Address> AllOwnerAddresses = home.Dogs.SelectMany(d = > d.Owner.Address).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the structure is a tree

```
static IEnumerable<Address> GetAddresses(Dog dog)
{ 
    yield return dog.Owner.Address;
    yield return dog.Kennel.Address;
    foreach (var addr in dog.Kennel.Dogs.SelectMany(dogC => GetAddresses(dogC)))
    {
        yield return addr;
    }
}
```